# jQuery extension to Prototype conversion

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am trying to convert the jQuery extension below into a Prototype like extension:

```
$.some = function(array, cmp_bool, context) {
    if (Array.prototype.some) {
        return array.some(cmp_bool, context);
    } else {
        if (context) {
            cmp_bool = $.proxy(cmp_bool, context);
        }
        return !!($.grep(array, cmp_bool).length)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

PrototypeJS has this already built in to the core.

The Array object type mixes in the Enumerable methods - which has the `some()` method with the exact same parameters (without the array as the first parameter as you are acting on the Array instance)

so given these

```
var testit = function(t){
    return t < 10;
}
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 7, 10];
```

the jQuery extension you've provided is invoked like this

```
$.some(myArray,testit);
//or noConflict() mode
jQuery.some(myArray,testit);
```

and the built-in PrototypeJS method is invoked like this

```
myArray.some(testit);
```

**The Enumerable method `some()` is aliased to the `any()` method which is linked here
http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/any/

Comment: Does anyone know what the equivalent of jQuery's methods $.proxy and $.grep in PrototypeJS is?

Comment: `$.proxy()` is the same as `bind()` http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bind/

Comment: $.grep is similar to `findAll()` http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/findAll/ - if you invert the jQuery $.grep that is `reject()` http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/reject/